# Force to use module-path in maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: java, maven, module, java-11, maven-compiler-plugin

Given this dependency tree:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ demo ---
[INFO] org.eclipse.angus:demo:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.angus:angus-mail:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.angus:angus-activation:jar:1.0.0:runtime
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
```

For some unexpected reason, the maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1 decides to compile it in the next way:

```
[DEBUG] Classpath:
[DEBUG]  /home/user/workspace/angus-mail/demos/demo/target/classes
[DEBUG]  /home/user/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/angus/angus-mail/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/angus-mail-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[DEBUG] Modulepath:
[DEBUG]  /home/user/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/2.1.0/jakarta.activation-api-2.1.0.jar
[DEBUG]  /home/user/.m2/repository/jakarta/mail/jakarta.mail-api/2.1.0/jakarta.mail-api-2.1.0.jar
[DEBUG] Source roots:
[DEBUG]  /home/user/workspace/angus-mail/demos/demo/src/main/java
[DEBUG]  /home/user/workspace/angus-mail/demos/demo/target/generated-sources/annotations
```

This is making compilation errors because org.eclipse.angus:angus-mail:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT is set in the classpath (instead of module-path). Then, the module inside of it is not considered for compilation.

This is the plugin configuration:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>11</source>
            <release>11</release>
            <target>11</target>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-compile</id>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <release>11</release>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>base-compile</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <release>11</release>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

That it is overriding a parent configuration that contains:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-compile</id>
                <configuration>
                    <release>9</release>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <!--
                        Configure compiler plugin to print lint warnings.
                        Need to exclude options warning because bootstrap
                        classpath isn't set (on purpose).
                        Need to exclude path warnings because Maven includes
                        source directories that don't exist (e.g., generated-sources).
                    -->
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Xlint</arg>
                        <arg>-Xlint:-options</arg>
                        <arg>-Xlint:-path</arg>
                        <!--
                            Too many finalize warnings.
                        <arg>-Werror</arg>
                        -->
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>base-compile</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <release>8</release>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>module-info.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>default-testCompile</id>
                <configuration>
                    <release>8</release>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

My questions are:

1. Why maven-compiler-plugin decides to put org.eclipse.angus:angus-mail:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT in classpath, and the other dependencies that depends on this one are set in module-path.
2. Is there anyway to force maven-compiler-plugin to not use classpath?.
3. How can this be fixed?.

This is the github branch to reproduce the issue:
https://github.com/jbescos/angus-mail/tree/testModules
To reproduce it:

```
cd demos/demo
mvn clean install

It seems the issue is that the plugin is invoked 2 times:
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (base-compile) @ demo ---
```

default-compile works and base-compile doesn't. I need to make only one compilation to fix it.

The solution is to add in the child pom maven-compiler-plugin the next to avoid the mess of the parent:

```
<inherited>false</inherited>
```

Still there is a funny error, that it compiles with JDK 7 and contains modulepath, even having the plugin correctly set to use JDK 11:

```
[DEBUG] -d /home/user/workspace/angus-mail/demos/demo/target/classes -classpath /home/user/workspace/angus-mail/demos/demo/target/classes: --module-path /home/user/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/angus/angus-mail/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/angus-mail-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/2.1.0/jakarta.activation-api-2.1.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/jakarta/mail/jakarta.mail-api/2.1.0/jakarta.mail-api-2.1.0.jar: -sourcepath /home/user/workspace/angus-mail/demos/demo/src/main/java:/home/user/workspace/angus-mail/demos/demo/target/generated-sources/annotations: -s /home/user/workspace/angus-mail/demos/demo/target/generated-sources/annotations -g -nowarn -target 1.7 -source 1.7 -encoding UTF-8 --module-version 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: Why do you have defined so many executions for the maven-compiler-plugin? What is the purpose of that? Please show the full pom files best would be having an example project on github or alike...

Comment: I have edited it to see how to reproduce the issue.
I don't know exactly the reasons to have such complex configuration.